# Problem while installing Fedora 20 on a system with Windows 7

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I am getting stuck at some point during a Fedora 20 installation from a live USB image.

I have a drive with 133GB space that I am going to use as free space to install Fedora. Here are the details:

[image]

Check the blue and red lines.

Once I deleted that existing partition to make it unallocated free space for Fedora, what is that red line area for? Same as free space even if I don't have any such drive?

Here is the result after deleting:

[image]

During the installation I get to the following step:

[image]

Why is there 0B space even if I have 133GB of unallocated space?
I don't understand this.

You can check my installation steps here [in this document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jKNrWC6qzaWVVLcWIzWFBFWERZU0c0VVkzRDJNdnhiUVNV/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please cut out the relevant parts of the images before uploading, that way they can be read without having to click them (especially nasty while trying to edit an answer)

Comment: @anthon edited images

Comment: what about custom partitionning, from there you should be able to select the partion you want to use without constraint

Answer (score 3):

You can normally only have four primary partitions on a harddisk, a limitation imposed by the partition table structure.

To get around this and get more partitions, the system creates an extended partition, which has its own partition table structure to hold more partitions.
The extended partition takes up one of the slots of the primary partitions.

I am not sure why Fedora doesn't try and use the available space in the extended partition. For SuSE and Ubuntu installations I don't recall needing a primary partition to get things to install.

You could try to reboot after deleting the extended partition, in case the installer did not notice the change to the disc. Or, alternatively, manually create partitions in the extended partition and allocate them to Fedora.